# Confusion in the proof of Rouché's theorem (joint continuity part)

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, rouches-theorem

> Let, $f,g$ be two holomorphic functions in a region $\Omega$. $C$ be a
>   circle in $\Omega$ containing interior such that $|f(z)|>|g(z)|\
>  \forall z\in C$. g vanishes nowhere on $C$. Then $f$ and $f+g$ have
>   same number of zeros inside $C$.

In the proof, we construct for each $t\in[0,1]$, $f_t=f+tg$. Then $f_t$ is non vanishing on $C$ and holomorphic on $\Omega$. So, by Argument principle ${1\over2\pi i}\int_{C}{f_t'(z)\over f_t(z)}dz=n_t=$#of zeros of $f_t$ inside $C$.
Now, we want to prove that ${f_t'(z)\over f_t(z)}$ is jointly continuous (hence uniformly continuous) on $[0,1]\times C$. If we can prove that $f_t$ is jointly continuous on $[0,1]\times C$, then $f'_t$ will follow similarly.
But I faced to prove the continuity.
Let $(t_0,z_0)\in[0,1]\times C$, choose $\varepsilon>0$,  $|f_t(z)-f_{t_0}(z_0)|=|f(z)-f(z_0)+tg(z)-t_0 g(z_0)|$. We need to find a $\delta>0$ such the expression is less than $\varepsilon$ for $\sqrt{(t-t_0)^2+|z-z_0|^2}<\delta$
How to find such $\delta$ and establish the continuity?
Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to give an actual answer, but I remember learning Rouche's theorem without any problems from [Cartan](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Analytic-Functions-Variables-Mathematics/dp/0486685438) (see exercise 19 on page 111).  A tiny book with a very clean exposition; I totally recommend it over any other source.

Comment: Okay,can you explain it when you have time?

Comment: Could be a while.

Comment: This is a terribly difficult way to prove Rouche's Theorem. Are you following along with some book? I'll take a look if you provide the title and page.

Comment: Yes I have seen another method of this proof. But there is another confusion . There we suppose $n_1,n_2$ be #of zeros of $f,f+g$ resp. And define $F=1+g/f$ Then applying Argument principle, we get $n_1-n_2={1\over2\pi i}\int_{C}{F'(z)\over F(z)} dz$ and due to $|f|>|g|$ on $C$, $F$ cannot be zero on $C$. Then they say $F$ is holo on whole $C$ and apply Cauchy theorem to conclude the integration to be $0$. But How? Inside $C$, $f$ has zeros, there $F$ should have poles right? Even more complicated when $g(z)=f(z)=0$. How get rid of these cases?

Comment: @BiswarupSaha you didn't ping me, so I didn't see your message sooner. Do you have a reference to this alternative proof? I'll take a look. Again, there are many, *many* ways to prove Rouche's Theorem, but I can't do much unless you expound a lot more or provide me the reference you're looking at. I'm happy to explain whichever proof you want (though I would recommend not using the one in your actual post... Joint continuity here is waaaay more machinery than you need to prove this, and goes against the intuition of the theorem imho)

Comment: @BiswarupSaha For example, in Ahlfors the proof is as follows: Call the boundary $\gamma$, and suppose $|f| > |g|$ on $\gamma$. Let $h = f + g$, so our condition says $|f| > |h - f| = |f - h|$ on $\gamma$. Note this implies both $f$ and $h$ are nonzero on $\gamma$. Dividing both sides by $|f|$, we have $|g/f - 1| < 1$ on $\gamma$. Thus, letting $F = g/f$, we know $F$ takes values only in the disk of radius $1$ centered at $1$ for $z \in \gamma$. In other words, the image under $F$ of $\gamma$ does NOT wind around the origin (the aforementioned disk does not contain $z = 0$)...

Comment: ... Now, note that $F$ has poles where $f = 0$ and has zeros where $g = 0.$ Denote the zeros of $f$ and $g$ by $Z_f$ and $Z_g$ respectively. Then, since $F(\gamma)$ does not wind around the origin, $0 = \int_\gamma \tfrac{F'}{F} = Z_g - Z_f$ *(note the integral is actually superfluous! We only need the $Z_g - Z_f$ part of the theorem)* so that $Z_f = Z_g$.